# findViewById returning null for views from another fragment -- views have id -1

Tags: android, fragment, findviewbyid

**Edit:** Stupid user error, I had malformed XML.

--

I have an activity with three fragments inside it.  In onResume() of one fragment, I am trying to grab views from another fragment using activity.[findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29), but that method is returning null for any of the views from one particular fragment.  Views in either of the other two fragments are fine.

If I dump the entire view tree using [getRootView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRootView%28%29) and the following quickly-hacked-together code, I see that the views in question are indeed part of the view tree, but **have an id of -1**.

```
private void dumpAllViews(View v, int indent)
{
    // Java doesn't support variable width format code -- "%*c"
    // Fake it with string concatenation.  Lame!
    Log.d(tag, String.format("%" + (indent * 4 + 1) + "c%s %d", ' ', v.toString(), v.getId()));
    if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
    {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)v;
        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            dumpAllViews(vg.getChildAt(i), indent + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Why would all the views in that fragment have id -1?

Edit: For the curious, here's the view tree that gets dumped out.  The problematic views are the ones inside of the second block, the view with id 2131165209.

```
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4057e118 -1
    android.widget.FrameLayout@4057e4f0 16908290
        android.widget.RelativeLayout@4057eee8 -1
            android.widget.FrameLayout@4057f2e0 2131165208
                android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout@40594dd0 -1
                    android.widget.RelativeLayout@405933e0 -1
                        android.widget.ImageView@405937d0 -1
                        android.widget.Button@40593b30 2131165223
                        android.widget.Button@40594260 2131165224
                        android.widget.TextView@40594820 -1
            android.widget.FrameLayout@4057f5b0 2131165209
                android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout@405972e0 -1
                    android.widget.RelativeLayout@40595588 -1
                        android.widget.ImageView@40595978 -1
                        android.widget.Button@40595cd8 -1
                        android.widget.Button@40596448 -1
                        android.widget.Button@40596b78 -1
            android.widget.TextView@4057f8c8 2131165210
            android.widget.FrameLayout@405805a8 2131165211
                android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout@40592c20 -1
                    android.widget.RelativeLayout@4058e1c0 -1
                        android.view.View@4058e5a8 2131165213
                        com.mycompany.MyCustomWidget@4058e7b8 -1
                        android.widget.TextView@40592158 2131165210
                        android.widget.TextView@405926c0 2131165259
            android.widget.RelativeLayout@40580878 2131165212
                android.view.View@40580cc8 2131165213
                android.widget.FrameLayout@40580e50 2131165214
                android.widget.FrameLayout@40581120 2131165215
            android.widget.LinearLayout@40581440 2131165216
                android.widget.FrameLayout@405816c8 2131165217
                android.widget.FrameLayout@40581930 2131165218
            android.widget.RelativeLayout@40581d00 -1
                android.widget.Button@40582878 2131165261
                android.widget.LinearLayout@40583ac0 -1
                    android.widget.Button@40583d48 2131165262
                    android.widget.Button@405846e0 2131165263
                    android.widget.Button@40585078 2131165264
                    android.widget.Button@40585a10 2131165265
                android.widget.LinearLayout@405863a8 -1
                    android.widget.Button@40586630 2131165266
                    android.widget.Button@40586e50 2131165267
                    android.widget.Button@40587670 2131165268
                    android.widget.Button@40587e90 2131165269
```

Edit 2: Here's all of the relevant XML.  First the "fragment container" layout, then the layouts of the individual fragments.  Everything after the "Center, halved" comment is unused at this time, but included for completeness.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <!--
    Total contents:
    Top bar
    Bottom bar
    Middle area (full screen)
    Middle area (half/half, tablet only)
    Middle area (40/60, tablet only)
    -->

    <!-- Note to self:
    Why are the placeholder FrameLayouts and not just Views?
    Once I get this bootstrapped I should try switching them
    to Views and see if that works just as well.
    -->

    <!-- Top -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <!-- Bottom -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="This space unintentionally left blank"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    <!-- Center, full -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/center_fragment_full"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_fragment"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_fragment"
        />

    <!-- Center, halved -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/center_fragment_half_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_fragment"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_fragment"
        >

        <View android:id="@+id/keystone"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            />

        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/center_fragment_half_left"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/keystone"
            />

        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/center_fragment_half_right"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/keystone"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Center, uneven split (roughly 40/60) -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/center_fragment_uneven_split_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_fragment"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_fragment"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/center_fragment_uneven_split_left"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/keystone"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />

        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/center_fragment_uneven_split_right"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/keystone"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/slide_out_menus"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the layout that gets substituted in for the top bar; its IDs are fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bars"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_3"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_4"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bar1"
        android:text="Title text"
        style="@style/style_2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the layout that gets substituted in the bottom bar; its IDs are broken:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bars"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_1"
        />
    <Button android="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        style="@style/style_1"
        android:text="foobar"
        />
    <Button android="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        style="@style/style_1"
        android:text="@string/menu"
        />
    <Button android="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="@style/style_1"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally, here's the layout that I currently have substituted in the middle; its IDs are fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <View android:id="@+id/keystone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <com.mycompany.MyCustomWidget
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_location_label"
        android:text="Current Location"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/keystone"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_location_data"
        android:text="City\nSTATE"
        android:textColor="#ACF"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/keystone"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: On a lark, I tried postponing the dump/findViewById until 1000 ms after onResume() by kicking off another thread.  No change, so it's not that something just hasn't finished initializing yet.  (Given that onResume() is 3 steps later in the fragment lifecycle than onCreateView(), I didn't expect this to be the problem.)

Comment: Another stab-in-the-dark, since the views in the fragment in question use IDs that are also defined in another unused-but-alphabetically-earlier layout file, I tried changing them to using new, unique IDs.  That didn't help either.

Comment: I don't know what the layout XML looks like but, since you're using RelativeLayout, are you sure the IDs of the controls are set with `android:id="@+id/name"` rather than `android:id="@id/name"`?

Comment: It might help if you also post the associated XML.

Comment: Douglas: good point.  I double-checked, and they are "@+id/name".

Comment: if you have references to the fragments, call getView().findViewById() and see if it finds it.

Comment: theelfismike: Done, posted as an edit.  I don't suppose there's any way to hide those behind a foldout button or something?  I couldn't find one in the markup help.

Comment: toadzky: I expect that won't work either but I'll give it a try.

(…)

Confirmed, fragment.getView().findViewById() also returns null, and dumpAllViews() of fragment.getView() show a view tree with no IDs (all -1).

Comment: Is there something in `style_1` that is overriding the id on those buttons? I notice those are the only controls have have `style_1` applied to them.

Comment: As noted above and below, I had malformed XML.  Given that, should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted the problem, and it was very much stupid user error, as expected.

```
android="@+id/button2"
```

should have been

```
android:id="@+id/button2"
```

Whoops!  Thanks all, and sorry for the stupid question.